# Spring 4 @Conditional: Environment properties not available unless @PropertySource is used

Tags: java, spring, properties

**Problem:**

When using `@Conditional` bean definitions within `@Configuration` classes, properties from external sources, e. g. files, are not available in the `Environment` when `Condition#matches` is evaluated - **unless** `@PropertySource` is used. Using `ConfigurationCondition` instead of `Condition` doesn't make a difference, no matter which `ConfigurationPhase` is used.

Since I also have the requirement to use wildcards for the names of my properties files, using `@PropertySource` is not an option, since it requires the locations to be absolute.  Spring Boot is completely off the table, so `@ConditionalOnProperty` is not an option either. This leaves me with defining a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean as the only remaining viable option.

**Question:**

Is there any way to define beans depending on the presence, absence or value of properties in the `Environment` using plain Spring mechanisms (not boot, and not some other hacky way) while also specifying property locations with wildcards and if so, what would need to be done?

**Example:**

In the following `JUnit` test, I expect a bean named `bean` to be available, iff the property `key` is available (i. e. not `null`) in the `Environment` during the evaluation of the `matches` method in the `PropertyCondition`. This is not the case, thus the test fails.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ConditionTest.ConditionTestConfiguration.class })
public class ConditionTest {

  private static final String PROPERTIES_LOCATION = "test.properties";
  private static final String BEAN_NAME = "bean";

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Test
  public void testBeanNotNull() {
    assertNotNull(applicationContext.getBean(BEAN_NAME));
  }

  @Configuration
  static class ConditionTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(PROPERTIES_LOCATION));
      return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(PropertyCondition.class)
    public Object bean() {
      return BEAN_NAME;
    }

  }

  static class PropertyCondition implements ConfigurationCondition {

    private static final String PROPERTY_KEY = "key";

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
      return context.getEnvironment().getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
      return ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN;
    }

  }

}
```

Once I add an `@PropertySource` annotation to the `ConditionTestConfiguration` like this:

```java
  @Configuration
  @PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
  static class ConditionTestConfiguration
```

the property `key` is available, thus the `PropertyCondition#matches` method evaluates to true, thus `bean` is available in the `ApplicationContext` and the test passes.

**Additional Information:**

- A file called `test.properties` containing `key=value` exists in the classpath
- I used a `ConfigurationCondition` with `ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN`, just to show that it doesn't change the behaviour for the better
- Package declaration and import statements are omitted for brevity

Comment: did you found answer to your question?